# How to add "-fstack-protector-all" to makefile?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

There is a error in my code:
    `*** stack smashing detected ***: ./mummergpu terminated`
I search it in stackoverflow, a solution is add `-fno-stack-protector` to environment variable， but i don't know how to add it ? can anyone help me ?
nakefile follow:

```
all: clean mummergpu
.SUFFIXES : .cu .cu_dbg_o .c_dbg_o .cpp_dbg_o .cu_rel_o .c_rel_o .cpp_rel_o .cubin
## Reenable this for testing all variations
#include ../experiments/test_rule.mk
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /usr/local/cuda-8.0
# Compilers
NVCC       := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc 
CXX        := g++ $(PROFILE)
CC         := gcc 
LINK       := g++ $(PROFILE)

# Add source files here
STATIC_LIB := libmummergpu.a
# Cuda source files (compiled with cudacc)
CUFILES     := mummergpu.cu
# C/C++ source files (compiled with gcc / c++)
CCFILES     := \
 mummergpu_gold.cpp suffix-tree.cpp PoolMalloc.cpp
```

Comment: Add `-fno-stack-protector` to your `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`. `-fno-stack-protector` is probably a bad idea, though. You should probably add `-fsanitize=undefined` or `-fsanitize=address` to your flags to help locate the error.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to add it ?like this ? CXXFLAGS  := $("fno-stack-protector")
CFLAGS    := $("fno-stack-protector")

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "-fstack-protector-strong" instead of "all".
With "-fstack-protector-all" it applies protection to all functions regardless they actually need this protection and hence make greater impact on performance.

Find more details here: https://lwn.net/Articles/584225/

The "Strong" stack protector aims to add stack protection only to those functions, which actually may need this protection.

You can use additional parameters to ./configure command to include stack protection:

```
./configure [options] CFLAGS='-fstack-protector-strong' CXXFLAGS='-fstack-protector-strong'
```

However, some packages may override this later.

Here is the command to apply stack protection for CFLAGS inside Makefile:
run:

```
sed '/^.*CFLAGS = / s/$/ -fstack-protector-strong' /path/to/Makefile
```

Once the output is verified and acceptable to apply changes on Makefile run sed with -i switch as follows:

```
sed -i '/^.*CFLAGS = / s/$/ -fstack-protector-strong' /path/to/Makefile
```